# Dynamically Created HTML element in an old Page shows in New Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am using plain NAVIGATION to navigate between two pages. Few Contents of first page is dynamically created

```
  <ul style="width:200px;float:left;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView1" data-inset="true"></ul> 
  <ul style="width:200px;float:right;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView2" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

I am appending LIST item in this List dynamically in first page

```
var $li = $("<li>").attr("data-filtertext",msg.userID).appendTo("#listView1");
        $("<a>").attr("href","#")
                .attr("id",msg.userID)
                .text(msg.userID)
                .appendTo($li)
                .css("background", "#F68D78");
        $("#listView1").listview('refresh')
```

I am navigating to another page using this menu

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="./index">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="./history">History</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

But when I am in new page I see ListItems which I had added dynamically in Index.ejs still shows in the new loaded page history.ejs but if I load history.ejs by simple refresh then the old ListItems does not show. The pages are all hosted by NodeJS and there are ROUTES to reach each one of them

Comment: Not clear what you asking, try to rephrase your question

Comment: The dynamically created Listitems shows in the new page.  The original page where those list items are created is index. Ejs and the new page where I am browsing via Anchor link is History. Ejs but all the dynamically created ListItem shows In History. Ejs